# Can I get mysql to search for an identical match on any rows in one column?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how to do ask this...

Is it possible to have mysql scan a whole column in a whole table and finds an identical match or matches.

So it would be something like...

```
$q = $pdo("SELECT ip FROM accounts");
$q -> execute();
$results = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (there is 2 of same ip) {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure what you're asking here

Comment: you mean `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE last_IP = [current_ip]` ?

Comment: Please could you rephrase the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for duplicates, the following SQL should give you any IPs listed two or more times in your accounts table.

```
$q= $pdo("SELECT ip FROM accounts GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip) > 1");
$q->execute();
$duplicateIPs = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You can also use `COUNT(*)>1` instead of `COUNT(ip)>1`. You count rows anyway (with same ip.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column,column2 FROM table WHERE last_login_ip = 'IPHERE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something along the lines of

```
SELECT `a`, `b`, COUNT(`a`) AS cnt FROM `table` AS t GROUP BY t.`a` ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```